# React table library that supports mutable data ( useRef )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Basically i'm looking for react table library that can take a mutable object ( to be specific an useRef object) as the main source of data to be displayed.

Basically i want to do something like this:

```
const TableViewComponent = () =>{
const tableData = useRef([{ rowName: 'test', value:0}] -> basically an array of objects that represents data for every row (the structure doesnt matter)
# code that receives data from server and updates the tableData.current with the data needed

return(
<Table data={tableData.current}/>
)
}
```

Basically, since i get a bunch of messages from the server and i update the data constantly (the number of rows stays the same), i don't want to rerender the table everytime. So i want to use the useRef to change the data thats being displayed on the table without triggering a rerender from react.

Im not sure if its something that can be done but any help is appreciated :). I tried react-table, rc-table but they didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it looks to me like you'll have to do it yourself.

There's *some* libraries that might help you  (like [`useTable`](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable) which focuses on headless components) but I don't think they offer what you're looking for.

So let's quickly do a mock-up! (note: this is a quick sketch, assume that the undefined variables are stored somewhere else or are given from the fetch)

```
function useTableData({ initialData, itemsPerPage, ...etc }) {
    const data = useRef(initialData);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        data.current = fetchFromSomeWhere(...etc);
        () => (data.current = null);
    }, [etc /* Place other dependencies that invalidate out data here*/]);

    const handleNewPage = useCallback(
        async ({ pageIndex }) => {
            if (!data.current[pageIndex * itemsPerPage]) {
                setLoading(true);
                data.current = [...data.current, await fetchMoreData(pageIndex)];
            }
            setLoading(false);
            return data.current;
        },
        [itemsPerPage, data, setLoading],
    );

    return [data, handleNewPage, loading];
}
```

Notice how every single thing returned from this hook is a constant reference except for the loading! Meaning, that we can safely pass this to a memoized table, and it won't trigger any re-renders.

```
const TableContainer = memo(etc => {
    const [data, handleNewPage, loading] = useDataForTable(...etc);
    return (
        <>
            {loading && <Spinner />}
            {/* Look ma, no expensive-renders! */}
            <Body {...{ data }} />
            <Pagination {...{ handleNewPage }} />
            <OtherActions />
        </>
    );
});
```

However, you might have noticed that the body won't re-render when we click on the next page! Which was the whole point of pagination! So now we need some sort of state that'll force the Body to re-render

```
const TableContainer = memo(etc => {
    const [currentPage, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [data, handleNewPage, loading] = useDataForTable(...etc);
    return (
        <>
            {loading && <Spinner />}
            {/* We're still re-rendering here :( */}
            <Body {...{ data, currentPage }} />
            <Footer {...{ handleNewPage, setPage }} />
            <OtherActions />
        </>
    );
});
```

And so we're left with a table that to use properly we need to:

1. Exercise restraint and properly invalidate old data. Otherwise, we'd be displaying incorrect data.
2. 'Unpack' the data from the current ref on the `Body` component, and then render it.

In essence, after all that work we're still left with a solution isn't particularly attractive, unless you have some really complicated actions or some expensive scaffolding around the TableComponent itself. This *might* however be your case.